# expected value of getting a head or a tail right after each other when flipping a fair coin

Tags: probability

we flip a fair coin N times. the probability getting a head or a tail is of course 0.5. after N tossings, we record a sequence of heads and tails. let A be the total number of times that we get a head right after we get a tail. let B be the total number of times that we get a tail right after we get a head. for example, if we flip the coin 7 times and record a result as HHTTHTH, then A=2 and B=2.
find E(A) and E(B).

i relate this problem to the famous coin changeover problem. i got stuck right from the beginning. thanks for any help.

Comment: For any given two consecutive flips, the _a priori_ probability of all four of these combinations is 0.25: HH, HT, TH, TT. So the probability that one flip is the opposite of the preceding flip is, ... wait for it, ... 0.25 + 0.25 = 0.50. Amazing! Every flip has an identical chance of being either heads or ails, and continues to be independent of the preceding flip, just as we assumed when we stated that the coin is fair.

Answer (score 2):

**A start:** Define random variables $X_1,X_2,\dots, X_{N-1}$ by $X_i=1$ if at $i$ we get a tail and at $i+1$ we get a head. So $X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_{N-1}$ is the number of tail to head transitions. By the linearity of expectation, $E(X_1+\cdots+X_{N-1})=E(X_1)+\cdots+E(X_{N-1})$.

But $\Pr(X_i=1)=\frac{1}{4}$, so the expected number of tail to head transitions is $\frac{N-1}{4}$.

For the variance, we would like to find first $E((X_1+\cdots+X_{N-1})^2$, and subtract the square of the expectation of $X_1+\cdots+X_{N-1}$. The calculation is similar to the previous one, but quite a bit more complicated. Expand $(X_1+\cdots+X_{N-1})^2$. Again, use the linearity of expectation.

**Added:** When we expand $(X_1+\cdots+X_{N-1})^2$, we get $\sum X_i^2$ plus "mixed" terms. The expectation of $\sum X_i^2$ has already been calculated, sine $X_i^2=X_i$. The mixed terms $X_iX_j$ can be divided into two types. The numbers $i$ and $j$ could be *consecutive*. For such $i,j$ we have $X_iX_j=0$. Or they could be non-consecutive. There are $\binom{N-1}{2}$ unordered pairs, of which $N-2$ are consecutive, leaving $\frac{(N-2)(N-3)}{2}$ non-consecutive pairs. For such a pair $\{i,j\}$, we have $\Pr(X_iX_j=1)=\frac{1}{2^4}$. But for each pair $\{i,j\}$ we have the term $2X_iX_j$. So the expectation of the mixed terms is $\frac{N-2)(N-3)}{2^4}$.

Comment: @ Andre Nicolas: thanks for your response. honestly i'm not as smart as you so i don't get why E[X] = (N-1)/4. could you also find the expected number of head to tail transition? is it also (N-1)/4?

Comment: For head to tail, sure, it is the same. For $E(X_i)$, by the usal way to calculate expectation this is $1\cdot \Pr(X_i=1)+0\cdot \Pr(X_i=0)$, or more simply just $\Pr(X_i)=1$. But $X_i=1$ if tail on $i$ **and** head on $i+1$, so the probability is $\frac{1}{2^2}$. Now add up, $i=1$ to $N-1$. Note that the $X_i$ are not independent, but linearity of expectation holds always. And it is not a question of smart, I have taught this sort of stuff many times.

Comment: i also get the expected number of head to tail transition is     (N-1)/4? Is that correct? i tried to calculate the var(X) but get stuck when expanding E[(X1 + X2 + ...Xn)^2]

Comment: When you expand, you get $X_i^3$ terms, easy since $X_i^2=X_i$. You also get $XiX_j$ terms, with $i\ne j$. Write down the condition for $X_iX_j$ to be $1$. Impossible if $j=i+1$. But if separated by at least $2$, probability is $\frac{1}{16}$. Now need to count.

Comment: @ Andre Nicolas: thanks for being with me. what you described is exactly where I got stuck. E[(X1 + X2 + ... Xn)^2] = E[X1^2 + ... Xn^2 + 2(X1X2 + ...Xn-1Xn)]. i don't know how to deal with the later part. could you please be more specific? thanks

Comment: @SeanJones: I have added most of the rest of the calculation, just have not the pieces together. Hope it is enough for you to push everything through. If there are further problems, please leave message. But I will be away fom the computer for a few hours.

Comment: @ Andre Nicolas: thanks a lot for your effort. i worked it out again and i get the following results. could you help me to check these? i really appreciate your efforts so far. E(A) = E(B) = (N-1)/4. var(A) = var(B) = (N-1)/4 - [(N-2)(N-3)]/8

Comment: @ Andre Nicolas: i also find it confused when it comes to cov(A,B). i use the formula cov(A,B) = E[A.B] - E[A].E[B]. we have E[A] and E[B] already. what hard to figure out is E[A.B]. could you express its meaning, E[A.B]? how could you calculate it? thanks a lot

Comment: @ Andre Nicolas: Are you still there? I still got stuck on this problem. If you have time, please come back.

Comment: I don't understand why N-2 pairs are consecutive. Can you explain more? Thank you.

Comment: They are the pairs $X_1X_2$, $X_2X_3$, and so on to $X_{N-2}X_{N-1}$. To count, note that the index of the first element in each pair is one of $1,2,\dots,N-2$.